# Not able to start Angular app with CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to run the Angular app with angular-cli. As per process, I follow the instruction on the website of CLI. But I got some issue and app does not start. Please check the screenshot

[image]

I am not getting any idea how to resolve it.

Comment: Hi , Have been succeed to run Hello world with CLI? And Can you please post the code or plunkr over here so that we get to know where you are stuck?

Comment: Re-install `angular-cli`. Then do `npm cache clean && rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get this error one of the following problems might be the cause:

1. The port you are trying to connect is already in use
2. The hosts file is corrupted somehow (`etc/hosts` or `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`)

Try to start the application with `ng serve --port 1234` or `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 1234` If the error persists try to restore the hosts file, follow this guide: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-set-the-windows-7-hosts-file-back-to-default

If none of these work there might be a problem with the node installation (be on the latest version)

Comment: If the port were in use, then the error message would tell you that. And what would this have to do with the `hosts` file?

Comment: I have encountered this error (or very similiar) before and after researching I found some solutions online that suggested this and it worked. It might be different here but worth a shot.

However its not a lot of information to work with.

Comment: @torazaburo Also what you suggested to do in your comment (reinstalling angular-cli) is probably what I'd do after I tried what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 1234 If the error persists try to restore the hosts file, follow this guide: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-set-the-windows-7-hosts-file-back-to-default

i use this... It start working ... Thanks :)